# Ubuntu boot stops after “Loading Initial ramdisk” - can’t start in recovery mode or using bootable USB

Tags: boot, grub2, recovery-mode

I have Ubuntu installed on Intel NUC 10 since mid 2020. It was working fine up until this week. The system doesn’t boot past “Loading initial ramdisk…” - automatically shuts down right after that message on the screen.

Same thing happens if I try to boot in recovery mode and also with bootable USB.

I’ve checked Grub to see if it’s reading the right hard drive partition. Most other solutions I’ve encountered require system to boot in either recovery mode or through bootable USB. Since I’m not able to boot from any avenue, looking for further guidance on next steps to solve the issue.

Comment: If it’s not booting *and* you’re unable to boot into a live usb session (and you’re sure that usb  media works, ie check you can boot into it on another computer) … then I think it must be a hardware issue. I’d start by removing a memory module and try again - and then take out a different one etc to exclude failed memory as the cause. It can’t be the hard drive if a live usb session won’t start - so likely memory / processor / mobo.

Comment: Thanks @Will. 

I tried booting with new ram but ran into the same issue. Got a new NUC and placed old ram and old hard drive into it and it booted fine. So I’m assuming the issue is with the motherboard. I moved my office and briefly used vacuum to pick up dust from the NUC’s surface. Maybe the vacuum static screwed up the motherboard.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a hardware issue.